# 2 different tables. Users and members show information about one

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two tables in mySQL, patient and users. In users I have 10 different columns

```
(
1   id  
2   username    
3   password    
4   salt    
5   email   
6   price   
7   firstname   
8   lastname    
9   univers varchar(255)    
10  studentid    
11  mobphone        
12  treatment 
)
```

and in patient I have 12 columns.

Upon logging in with a user account I want to be able to see what's in the patient table. And if I log in with a patient account I want to be able to see what's inside the user table.

How do I connect them?

Comment: Do you really mean 10 columns and 12 columns?

Comment: yes thats what i mean :P

Comment: So you want a `JOIN`?